# Extending or overriding a model from Base

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

I am trying to add new properties to a model that is my Base library which I installed it from nuget and trying to add new property in the project where I installed my Base

Model in Base

```
public class Product
{
  int Id{ get; set; }
  string Name{ get; set; }
  string Status{ get; set; }
}
```

In my project, I would like to add a new property called Code (string) without changing the model name

I tried doing this by inheriting the Base Context and ignoring the Base Model as below

```
public class PDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public PDataContext() : base()
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;            
            Database.SetInitializer<PDataContext>(null);
        }

        public new DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();            
            modelBuilder.Ignore<ClientApi.Base.Models.Product>();
        }
    }
```

The above did not work as it threw an exception `"The entity type Product is not part of the model for the current context."`

**May I know a best way to do this?**

Comment: You ignored the type Product for the model, so either your DbSet has to have a different type or you'll have to remove the Ignore statement (in order to query you'll still have to edit the type for it to have the additional property)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include it in your post, but I assume the entity you'd like to use inherits from Product and includes an extra property `Code` something like this?

```
public class MyProduct : Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, you can use `MyProduct` in your context instead of `Product`:

```
public class PDataContext : DataContext
{
    public PDataContext() : base()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;            
        Database.SetInitializer<PDataContext>(null);
    }

    public new DbSet<MyProduct> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyProduct>().ToTable("Product");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I am still trying not to change the name of the table

Comment: @Dolt please review the answer now, I've added a line to keep the table name the same as well.